# Printing elements in a queue in a different function does not empty the queue globally in _start program. Any more explanation?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, stl, c++14

Probably this is rather a simple question but I cannot wrap around why the result is what it is.
Consider the following simple code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

void print_queue(std::queue<int> q)
{
    while( !q.empty() )
    {
       std::cout << q.front();
       q.pop();
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The size of the queue in the print function: " << q.size() << std::endl;
}


int main() {

   std::queue<int> my_queue;
   for ( const int &item : {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} )
   {
       q.push(item);
   }
   print(my_queue);
   std::cout << "The size of the queue in the main loop: " << my_queue.size() << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

The expected output of this will be:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
The size of the queue in the print function: 0
The size of the queue in the main loop: 7
```

My question is why there is no side effect on the queue I am trying to print out.
Wasn't the queue supposed to be empty at both times when the size was printed out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `print_queue` and the function `main` deal with two different queues. You should pass the queue in main by reference.

That is the parameter of the function `print_queue` shall be a referenced type. For example

```
void print_queue(std::queue<int> &q)
                                 ^^
```

Otherwise the function deals with a copy of the original queue. As a result the original queue is not being changed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If I want to write cleaner, will I better use ``` const std::queue<int> &q``` as a input to the function and make a copy of it, and use the local copy instead?

Comment: @bad_locality If you declare the queue as constant when you will be unable to change it.  So it depends on what you are going to do with the queue.

Comment: Yes I see. Just asking for more info, if I dont want the queue to be changed as input, what will be cleaner? Pass by reference and copy it explicitly inside the function, or pass it as it is and the function can deal with a copy?

Comment: @bad_locality In this case there is no need use a reference. Just use your initial approach of passing the queue by value.